# incorrect syntax when trying to create a url variable

Tags: python

Importing and API into a URL variable, but when I add the link it says invalid syntax because of the ' ' for the name.

after get my title the first ' in the demo list end the link. How do I get get the syntax correct so that it finishes the entire url.

url ='https://sitename/sites/org/subsite/test/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Demo List')/items'

Comment: You need to make one set of quotes double quotes and leave the other set single quotes. It doesn't matter which.

Comment: @evergreen it actually does matter, since the string value will be different.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have apostrophes in your string, then you could put your text between quotation marks instead of apostophes. It should look like this:

`url ="https://sitename/sites/org/subsite/test/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Demo List')/items"`

Answer (score 0):

You can put a backslash character followed by the quote ( \' ). This is called an escapesequence and Python will remove the backslash, and put just the quote in the string.

```
url ='https://sitename/sites/org/subsite/test/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'Demo List\')/items'
```

This way, you can have any number of quotes in your string and omit them by using backslash.